# Norwegian Air ticket conversion to CashPoints because of COVID19 is not working for me, why?

Tags: tickets, covid-19, refunds, norwegian-air-shuttle

I had booked a ticket for two for June 2020 from Bulgaria to Finland before COVID19 happened. Now I want to cancel or refund my ticket, but the only option there is on the website of Norwegian Airline is CashPoints refund of the ticket. I am ok with that, but when I clicked to do that and fill my booking ID and last name I got this message:

> Information
>   Your profile does not have a reward membership. In order to claim a refund with cashpoints, please go to My Travels to sign up for reward.

I have a reward number. I go to my profile, but I don't know what I am supposed to do next!

Someone know what I should do? There is no email address of Norwegian Airlines and their phone is not being answered. Can anyone help me and tell me what I should do?

[This is the website](https://www.norwegian.com/uk/ipr/refund#/cashpoints)

Comment: note that if _you_ cancel you might be in much worse situation than if _they_ cancel - the latter gives you full money back. it might be a good idea to wait it out.

Comment: @Aganju, thank you for the hint. Do you have a specific amount of days I can cancel before the flight?

Answer (score 1):

At the top right of the Norweigian webpage you cite, next to the Norwegian logo, is a sign-in button. Select that.

On the next page, fill out the "I already have a profile" boxes, and click "sign in."

The next page will display your profile. On the bottom of that page, select the "Upcoming Trips" tab. The page should then display your upcoming reservation. Altervatively, you could select the "Find Booking" tab, and enter the booking reference and your name. This should have the same result.

Click on the reservation. Doing so should take you to an expanded presentation of your reservation, and somewhere on that page there should be a button or tab for change or cancellation.

Comment: yes, I am doing that and it is not working. I still have the same message.

Comment: I'm sorry. Try entering your information on this other Norwegian Cancel-and-Claim page: https://www.norwegian.com/uk/ipr/refund#/cashpoints This page appears to have been recently set up as a result of the Covid crisis, and it may work better. Otherwise, you can call and be (very) patient on the phone, or use FB or Twitter or other social media.

Comment: Yes, I used this website and I am getting the error from this website. I tried it like 1 million times already. I tried to contact them by phone waiting for 30 mins nothing happen. I tried to contact them on FB, still no answer after 3 days. Send them a ticket and still no answer after 3 days.

Comment: btw your answer its not relevant to my question. the whole problem is that I am doing everything right and I still get this error

Comment: Perhaps someone else will chime in with a suggestion. BTW, in this post-Covid time, it's difficult or impossible to reach airlines generally. 20 minutes on hold is minor; hours and hours is more common. Three days without an online answer is much shorter than airlines' "We'll take weeks (or months) to get back to you" warnings about electronic communication.

Comment: thats fine, but what if they dont cancel my flight and i have to flight? then i will loose my money :/

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a very quick answer, but I was in a situation where my flight got cancelled by Norwegian (I had a flight during the lockdown). I requested for a refund (not cash points) and it was taking a while. I contacted Norwegian via Twitter (@Fly_Norwegian) and they responded to me there faster than the phone.

Edit: I filed the request on 6 May, contacted Norwegian on Twitter on 23 May (because I couldn't get them on the phone), got a boilerplate response within the day, respondee to the tweeet, another response on 25 May. Then an email confirming that my claim was processed on 29 May. Received the reimbursement in my account today, 3 June.

Comment: How many days it took to get the refund?

Comment: I filed the request on 6 May, contacted Norwegian on Twitter on 23 May (because I couldn't get them on the phone), got a boilerplate response within the day, respondee to the tweeet, another response on 25 May. Then an email confirming that my claim was processed on 29 May. Will come back to this post once the refund is in my account ;)